# How to find a constant processor thief in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js server running on a linux box (ubuntu 12lts)

When I run the top command I always have approx 11-13% of processor to node.js. I have had it like this for a couple of months and I can notice that some of  my other node servers dont behave like this.

Are there any good ways of finding processor thieves in Node? And in particular things that tend to run constantly?

Comment: Can you post some code. What is this node server doing?

Comment: Use node-inspector or nodetime to see CPU/memory profiles.

Comment: It is a fairly big server so posting code would be difficult. Especially since I dont know where the problem is in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you implement at least some logging functionality, looks like [this](http://jpallen.net/2013/03/08/tracking-down-a-memory-leak-in-node-js-and-socket-io/) article can help you...

Comment: Yeah that seems to be a good method at least if there is a memory issue, which I dont have. I liked the article, useful thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this. I will try to implement it. 
https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent